# Swift how to solve unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9e0d8b7c0

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uigesturerecognizer

I add a long press in my collectionviewcell with

```
lp = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longPress:"))
lp.delegate = self
cell.tag = indexPath.row
cell.addGestureRecognizer(lp)
```

but if I push to other viewController and popback with swipe, the project will crash!

So I look for website to solve this problem, and I know the reason is I don't get a UIGestureRecognizer for delegate

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(g: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

And I got this exception

> ***gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9e0d8b7c0
>   2015-03-15 18:56:08.733 PicMemo[62182:5214628]Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PicMemo.iViewController gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa9e0d8b7c0'***

I think I got a solution in [uilongpressgesturerecognizer crashes even if not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239143/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-crashes-even-if-not-implemented)

But I don't know how to do with Swift.

Comment: you havn't implemented a method named"longpress"

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Comment: The class name which you omitted in the exception message does not implement the named method.

Comment: @HotLicks I implemented the method but when I pop back , I got the exception.So the method gestureRecognizerShouldBegin had not executed.

Comment: The class name which you omitted in the exception message does not implement the named method.

Comment: @HotLicks I got That!!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @HotLicks
There is a solution:
We should add ***UIGestureRecognizerDelegate***
Then add

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

finally

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {

    //self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) is also ok
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    return true;
}
```